# is it possible to Run node js executables in USS/OMVS mainframe?

Tags: node.js, server, mainframe, uss, omvs

I have created a node js Executable .exe file for windows and executable for linux using pkg. But I when try running these files in OMVS/USS, not working with error "FSUM7332 syntax error: got ), expecting new line". I think there is a problem with EBCDIC conversion. Is there any possible way to run these executable in USS/OMVS mainframe? Please suggest. Thanks!?

I am trying start nodejs server using executable file in USSOMVS mainframe (.exe file)

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail I think yout assessment that its a codepage issue is probably one of several issues.

I wouldn't expect an exe file to run on z/OS USS as exe is a Windows extension.  you may be able to target zLinux but as it appears that a binary of some sort is included its not likely to run on USS.

I would first place your App in the USS environment on z/OS and use `npm` to pkg your application up.  See if that works and go from there.

Comment: Thanks hogstrom! I was trying run nodejs rest using bundled executable file instead of source files. It works with npm run build and node. But I want to see if it works with bundled executable file as well in USS/OMVS